# What are few datasets that we can use to build OCR model to detect text from documents like resumes etc.,?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, ai, deep-learning

Do any-one know few good annotated OCR datasets that we can use to train a OCR model for detecting text from documents like resume (i.e., document image)?

Comment: Are handwritten documents by writers aceptable??

Answer (score 1):

**[IAM Online Document Database (IAMonDo-database)](http://www.iapr-tc11.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=IAM_Online_Document_Database_(IAMonDo-database))**

**Description**

The dataset contains 941 online handwritten documents by 189 writers. The documents consist of text blocks, lists, tables, formulas, diagrams, and drawings. Such pieces of content have been placed in arbitrary positions on each document.

Some of the documents have landscape orientation, others have portrait orientation. On some documents, separate text parts have a different orientation.

The dataset contains:

```
941 documents
68841 words
7616 text lines in text blocks
1478 text blocks
2068 list items
536 lists
2550 table cells
450 tables
5698 labels in diagrams
917 drawings in diagrams
910 diagrams
546 drawing not part of diagrams
489 formulas
355,097 strokes
```

More

[15 Best OCR & Handwriting Datasets for Machine Learning](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/15-best-ocr-handwriting-datasets/)